# What is a Jesus Spot / Room?

Tags: terminology, left-4-dead-series

In *Left 4 Dead* and *Left 4 Dead 2*, there are numerous guides that refer to getting to a **Jesus Spot** or **Jesus Room**.

What exactly is a Jesus Spot/Jesus Room?

Why is it called a Jesus Spot/Jesus Room?

Is this term used in any other games?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search turned up [this GameFAQs post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/937407-left-4-dead/answers/120046-the-jesus-room):

> "the Jesus room" is the name commonly used for the room under the satellite, on the rooftop finale of the No Mercy campaign. Once inside this room there is a glitch that makes it so no zombies can come in whether common, special, or tank. Eventually if you wait long enough both hordes of zombies will completely die, along with the two tanks prior to the helicopter's arrival. Note that once the helicopter shows up their is an infinite number of zombies and tanks, so it would be unwise to linger. Also one or two zombies have been known to find their way in "the Jesus room" and i personally can recall a tank coming in after me. To get in "the Jesus room" stand above the doorway into it and the zombies will break open the door while attempting to climb over it.

It seems as though the room is a specific location in the game, and referring to a "Jesus Spot" would be a broader description of a location where this behavior/glitch can be observed.

Given the context, I would expect that this *concept* can be applied to other games, however, I doubt that the name is really common other than in L4D (which I have never played and have not heard this term until now).